# Can you run unit tests as part of building your app in Xcode 5?

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, xcode5, xctest

In Xcode 4.x any unit tests (logic tests) could run as part of building your main target.

Is a similar setup possible for Xcode 5?

Update

The issue boils down to Xcode launching the simulator as part of running logic tests. That wasn't the case with Xcode 4.x

Have created a radar to track this http://openradar.appspot.com/15859153

Answer (score 0):

To build and run unit tests after building the other targets in the active scheme, use command-U.